# ASP.NET Theming Programmatically: Image Paths

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, themes

We have a multilingual site, or culture-sensitive, and some of the static content now needs to be targeted; for this I'm using themes as it *seems* the easiest way to achieve what I want, but I can't for the life of me get the images to pick up.

I'm setting the theme in code-behind, and thought at first that maybe this was the issue, but on checking up it looks like I'm doing the right thing (setting on `Pre-Init`).

I expect to be able to reference images using relative paths where `App_Themes/ThemeName/` is automatically resolved, such as:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="images\image.jpg"/>
```

For whatever reason, however, the image isn't being pulled through at all.

This is the code we have in place for setting the theme (the only really relevant part, I'm sure, being the `Theme = CurrentSite.CultureName`, which is applied successfully):

```
Private Sub SetTheme()
    Dim themesPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Themes")
    If Directory.Exists(themesPath) Then
        Dim themePaths = Directory.GetDirectories(themesPath)
        Dim themePathInfo As DirectoryInfo
        For Each _path In themePaths
            themePathInfo = New DirectoryInfo(_path)
            If Not themePathInfo Is Nothing Then
                If themePathInfo.Name = CurrentSite.CultureName Then
                    Theme = CurrentSite.CultureName
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

In the above code, `CurrentSite.CultureName` would be a language culture name (for example, en-gb, or nn-no) that does have an existing corresponding theme folder containing all required resources.

Pages do have `EnableTheming` set to `True`. Also, I have tried removing the theme-setting code and applying the theme in the page using `Theme="en-gb"` to no avail.

Is there anything immediately evident as to why the URLs aren't resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Skin file to do this. Change your Image tag to:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" SkinID="SomeImage/>
```

And in your `App_Themes\MyTheme\` folder, add a new Skin file (MyTheme.skin) and add this:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" SkinID="SomeImage" ImageUrl="images\image.jpg"/>
```

This image skin now points to `image.jpg` within the `App_Themes\MyTheme\` folder.

For dynamic images you can do this in your BasePage (assuming you have one):

```
public string ThemePath { get { return "~/App_Themes/" + this.Theme + "/"; } }

public string MapThemePath(string relativePath)
{
    return string.Format("{0}{1}", this.ThemePath, relativePath);
}
```

But, since I can't see what you're actually doing, I can't say this is the recommended solution. In general your theme contains only things needed or layout and display. You're talking about dynamic images which, to me, doesn't sound like it belongs in a theme? Not sure, just a thought.

Comment: For every image? This is my main concern as some images are generated on the fly depending on data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; this is kind of what I was putting off but looks like it may be the only solution - for the time being at least.

Comment: In my opinion it's not a bad solution since ASP.Net doesn't currently provide a way to do this (that I know of). Another thing I've done is make a "ThemeImage" control that inherits from Image and maps the ImageUrl to the theme.